# How to add Image on twitter using php code?

Tags: php, twitter

Already I searched for the propose and I found many answer but not helpful , and I posted Text on twitter easily but , when I tried to post Image I got bool(false) Error , the below code I used for posting image but not working till now , kindly help me , what's the error of my code :

```
<?php

require 'tmhOAuth.php';
require 'tmhUtilities.php';
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
  'consumer_key'    => '***************',
  'consumer_secret' => '***************',
  'user_token'      => '***************',
  'user_secret'     => '***************',
));

$image = 'myImage.jpg';

$code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', 'https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
  array(
    'media[]'  => "@{$image}",
   "status"   => "Is this working now?"
  ),
  true, // use auth
  true  // multipart
);

if ($code == 200) {
  var_dump(json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response']));
} else {
  var_dump($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
}
?>
```

My result is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong API call.

According to [the official documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media) the correct request is to:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json
```

It may also be worth your while to check you're using the latest version of the PHP library.